# prove that $|G|$ is even if $g=g^{-1} $, for all $g \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

my Attempt: we know that $id,g$ form a Subgroup of $G$ and by Lagrange theorem the order 
of a subgroup of $G$ divides the order of $G$.

are we done already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim as stated is not correct, because of the trivial group. Otherwise, your argument works, and just needs $g=g^{-1}$ for some $g \ne \mathbf{1}_G$ and not all $g \in G$.

Comment: Yes $G$ is not the trivial group and the "for all" condition was necessary to prove another part of the exercise. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $|G|$ is odd and for every $g\neq e_G$, $g^2=1$, so $2\big||G|$. Otherwise we have to assume that $G=\{e_G\}$.

Comment: Simple and to the point! +1

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple application of Lagrange's theorem. Let $x\in G$ such that $x^2 = 1_G$ and consider the generated subgroup $\langle x \rangle$, then you will  have that $|\langle x \rangle | = |\{x,1_G \}| = 2$ so now using Lagrange's theorem 2 divides $|G|$ i.e. $|G|$ is even. Note that we require that $x\neq 1_G$ and that we only need one element in the group that satisfy the hipothesis.